# Angular $compile returns comment without a nextElementSibling for Elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've written a directive which replaces anchors with spans if a flag is set to "disable" them. To do this, I keep both the original and a replacement element and swap out as needed.

However, this is proving painful when the element also has an Angular directive like `ng-if` - because during `$compile` angular pollutes the template with comments.

I've discovered that when I compile a string template, I can access the actual element I want via `nextElementSibling` (the returned node is a `Comment`).

Yet when I compile an actual `Element`, this fails. All I get back is the `Comment`.

```
// Compiling with an Element
var $span = document.createElement('span');
$span.setAttribute('ng-if', true);

var $compiled = $compile($span)($scope);
$timeout(function() {
  console.log($compiled[0], $compiled[0].nextElementSibling);
  // => <!-- ngIf: true -->  null
});


// Compiling with a string template
var span = '<span ng-if="true"></span>'

var $compiled = $compile(span)($scope);
$timeout(function() {
  console.log($compiled[0], $compiled[0].nextElementSibling);
  // => <!-- ngIf: true --> <span ng-if="true" class="ng-scope"></span>
});
```

I don't know why they'd behave differently, they should be producing the same end result. I can't keep a valid reference to the element unless it's built from a string template.